# Phaser Can't spawn a sprite from a sprite sheet correctly

Tags: sprite, phaser-framework, sprite-sheet

I made an 8-frame sprite sheet to use in a walking animation, and I'm trying to use the sprite sheet to spawn a single frame to use when the character isn't moving.

This is the code I'm using to load the sprite sheet:

```
this.load.spritesheet('PeefSide', "assets/PeefSide.png", {frameWidth: 50, frameHeight: 
60});
```

And this is the code that I'm using to spawn a single sprite:

```
this.p1 = this.physics.add.sprite(1535, 730, 'PeefSide');
```

But for some reason, instead of a single sprite, the entire sprite sheet spawns in the level. I'm not sure what I did wrong, so can someone provide a solution?

If it helps, I'm using phaser 3 in VSCode with arcade physics.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the **frame-size** of the *phaser-spritesheet* is too big *(or the actual image, that is loaded, is to small)*.

Check the **frame-size** (`frameWidth` and `frameHeight`) from the `this.load.spritesheet(...)`, with the actual image size, and alter the images size, so that the image `width` and `height` is **exact** multiple of the `frameWidth` and `frameHeight`, this should solve your problem.

Similar as mentioned in *[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72789894/1679286)*

Comment: I get why this would cause problems, but even with this I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong. The entire sprite sheet's size is 400 x 60, so I believed that frameWidth: 50 and frameHeight: 60 would give me a 50 x 60 sprite.

Comment: @EmptyStone this is really strange, since  just saw this error happen, when the image is too small to fit the _frame-Size_ . Is there a error Message in the Browser-Console?

Comment: No, there's no error message.

Comment: Managed to sole the issue. I wasn't doing anything wrong, I just hadn't placed this code in all the scenes where the sprite is used.

Comment: @EmptyStone Perfect, I'm glad you could solve it! If possible, and it is not too much trouble, could you create an answer, with the *code that was missing*, so that others, that might have the same issue, could find the solution faster? Thanks you in advance

Comment: Not really any new code to show actually. It turns out I had the code right from the beginning, it's just that I had only added it to one scene, and not the scene that the player first sees when starting the game. I stupidly thought it was a bigger problem and made this post. dang it.

Comment: @EmptyStone I understand, that can happen. :) In any case thanks for the information.